Postman performance testing results make no sense
I'm using Postman to performance test an endpoint on an ASP.NET Core web service. The endpoint performs a single simple DB operation using Entity Framework and SQL Server.
I've tested the implementation of this endpoint using benchmarking in the web service itself (just creating a DbContext from DI and running the query in an async loop) and running against LocalDB, it handles several thousand requests per second.
I now want to test it using Postman to see what effect the networking and routing have on the throughput.
I have a collection containing a single request, which I run with 20 virtual users for 1 minute. Postman outputs this:

To me this makes no sense. Postman is saying that each request completed (on average) in 7 ms, but that only 17.2 requests per second were handled!
If each request took ~7 ms then in a one second a single user should have made 1000/7 requests, which is around 140 requests per second, per user.
What's going on here?
UPDATE
Ran same test using Bombardier and got numbers that make sense.
PS C:\Users\Martin\Downloads> .\bombardier-windows-amd64.exe --connections=20 https://localhost:7108/api/benchmarks/benchmark2
Bombarding https://localhost:7108/api/benchmarks/benchmark2 for 10s using 20 connection(s)
[=================================================================================================================] 10s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
Reqs/sec      7292.63    2150.11   25063.79
Latency        2.74ms     1.93ms    52.32ms
HTTP codes:
   1xx - 0, 2xx - 72937, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0
   others - 0
Throughput:     1.55MB/s


If you're seeing issues with the numbers or data returned from Postman, can you raise that as an issue on https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support

I think 17.2 requests per second is how fast Postman is sending requests.

Since Bombardier is sending a LOT more requests per second, it makes sense that the latency is much higher.  (and it's sending all those requests in 10 seconds, where postman is spreading them out over 68 or so secs...)

Bombardier was configured to use 20 users querying in parallel, and Postman was configured to use 20 virtual users, which is supposed to be the same thing. The Postman documentation also states that each virtual user will run the query repeatedly for the specified time period.
So both tools are configured to perform the same test.
